# Variable annotated with [SerializeField] not showing up in inspector

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with a variable which is not showing up in the inspector even though I have declared it a serialized field.

Code:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class SettingsPopup : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Slider speedSlider;

    private void Start()
    {
        speedSlider.value = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("speed", 1);
    }
    ....
}
```

[Unity inspector screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOIRi.png)

I am using Unity 2019.2.10f1 Personal.
edit: changing the type of speedSlider to anything outside the UnityEngine.UIElements namespace makes it appear in the inspector.

Comment: Is `Slider` a class that you wrote or is it the one from Unity?

Comment: @MaxPlay Slider in this case is UnityEngine.UIElements.Slider which is provided by Unity

Comment: Do you have any compile-errors? The serializer does not update, when there are errors. Have you tried setting the field to public? Just to see what happens.

Comment: @MaxPlay I have tried setting the variable to public, did not change anything. I have recompiled the code and restarted Unity a few times. Unity at some point complained that speedSlider had its default value null, however this message is gone now.

Comment: Okay, I dug a bit through the [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/tree/master/Modules/UIElements) of the UI Elements Module and saw that Slider (well, actually anything in there) is not marked as serializable and does not inherit from MonoBehaviour. I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible. You can probably access it via some bindings by using its container (which should be assignable). [This might help](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIE-Binding.html)

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will look into that.

Comment: If `Slider` is part of the new UIElements AFAIK those need to have a custom inspector created with UXML. See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIElements.html

Comment: If you ment a `UnityEngine.UI.Slider` from the previous UI system you'll have to install the according Package!

Answer (score 3):

Try namespace UnityEngine.UI not UnityEngine.UIElements;

Answer (score 1):

If you want a slider for the UI control, an attribute needs to be used to decorate the field, e.g. `[Range(1, 100)]`. The way the code is written it is asking the editor to use a control that allows the user to provide something of type `Slider` for the field value, rather than the intended `float`.

This will show a slider control in the editor:

```
[Range(1.0f, 100.0f)] public float speed;
```

Comment: and if OP wanted a `Slider`?

Comment: If you mean a UIElements slider, a complete UXML + code  + CSS solution needs to be created. My inference from the context of the original question was that a slider control to select a numeric value in the default editor inspector was desired.